# how to parse the server side xml code into normal java code

Tags: android, xml

presently iam trying to work with the youtube data api,on searching in net i found 1 link like
http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/649-working-with-gdata-apis-youtube-on-android.html
so in this how to parse the youtube server side xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use an DocumentBuilderFactory to parse and output and HttpClient to download yoru XML. for a tutorial on how to do that check out: http://p-xr.com

There is a good tutorial available for this subject.

Wesley.